# redirect_to not working in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect

In Rails side, I have two controllers: A_controller and B_controller. And when the client side hits one of the actions in A_controller, it probably gets an exception. And when the exception happens, I would like to have the rails redirects to a new page (under B_controller). So, below is what I did:

```
class AController < ApplicationController 
  rescue_from SampleException, :with => :redirect_to_page_b

  def redirect_to_page_b
    redirect_to "/b/#{@id}"  # a URL here
  end 
end
```

However, when the browser didn't redirects to the new page and I debugged with the ajax call and noticed that the response is success with status = 200. Why does this happen?

Comment: are you calling your action from AJAX ? if that's the case .. AJAX responses cannot be redirected from server response

Comment: That's right, @sa77 . And do you know how to redirect in AJAX response? Thanks.

Comment: you need to do that with javascript on success block of your AJAX call ... something like `window.location = 'example.com/take-me-here'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do an ajax request, you probably request `json` or `js` format. But your `redirect_to` is response for `html` format, so it just does nothing.

Depending on what format you request, you can handle the error differently.

If you request `js` format, you can keep the rescue in your controller and do:

```
def redirect_to_page_b
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to "/b/#{@id}" }
    format.js { render js: "window.location = '/b/#{@id}'" }
  end
end
```

Requesting a `json` format, I would remove the `rescue` block from the controller and let the error to happen. Then I would handle it in the `fail` block of the ajax call.
Or if you need only to handle specific type of exception, you can still keep the rescue and respond there with such json:

```
render json: { redirect_link: "/b/#{@id}" }
```

then in `done` callback of your ajax call you can check presence of `redirect_link` in the response, and if it's there, assign it to `window.location`.

Comment: Wow, perfect answer! Thank you!